# R - as.numeric matrix

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to convert a dataframe to a numeric matrix using the below code

```
expData <- read.table("GSM469176.txt",header = F)
expVec <- as.numeric(as.matrix(exp_data))
```

When I use as.matrix, without as.numeric, it returns some numbers (as below)

```
0.083531    0.083496    0.083464    0.083435    0.083406    0.083377    0.083348"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[9975] "-0.00285  -0.0028274  -0.0028046  -0.0027814  -0.0027574  -0.0027319  -0.0027042
```

but when I put in the as.numeric, they are all converted to "NA"

I apologize if someone has asked this question before but I can't find a post that solves my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add output of `dput(expData)` to the question. That will help us recreate `expData` on our end.

Comment: Can you edit in the first few lines of data file as well?

Comment: Looks like your `read.table` is not doing what you think it's doing

Comment: My amazing psychic powers are suggesting the text file might be available here - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM469176

Comment: Need to edit your question; it's expData in the first line and exp_data in the second.

Comment: your psychic powers are correct!!!

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 issues. First, if you examine the structure of the data frame, you'll note that the first column is characters:

```
head(expData)[, 1:4]

            V1         V2         V3         V4
1 YAL002W(cer) 6.1497e-02 6.2814e-02 6.4130e-02
2 YAL002W(par) 7.1352e-02 7.3262e-02 7.5171e-02
3 YAL003W(cer) 2.2428e-02 3.8252e-02 5.4078e-02
4 YAL003W(par) 2.6548e-02 3.6747e-02 4.6947e-02
5 YAL005C(cer) 2.4023e-05 2.3243e-05 2.2462e-05
6 YAL005C(par) 2.0252e-02 2.0346e-02 2.0440e-02
```

Therefore, trying to convert the complete data frame to numeric will not work as expected.

Second, you are running as.numeric() after as.matrix(), which is converting the matrix to a vector:

```
x <- as.numeric(as.matrix(expData))
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 
class(x)
[1] "numeric"
dim(x)
# NULL not a matrix
length(x)
# [1] 14261302
```

I suggest you try this:

```
rownames(expData) <- expData$V1
expData$V1 <- NULL
expData <- as.matrix(expData)
dim(expData)
# [1] 7502 1900
class(expData[, 1])
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Spot on for the first point. However, the second, while it may mess with the dim, should have no impact on the values.  The OP states that s/he is getting **all** `NA`s suggesting a different issue

Comment: True, it does not impact the values. But it does impact what they are trying to achieve (a matrix). Although given that they called their variable expVec, I wonder if they really do want a matrix?

Comment: Agreed, I think a data.frame is what they need, just calling it a matrix

Comment: The use of the term "matrix" when you mean 'dataframe' is bad advice for R-newb..

Comment: @Dwin, I meant that _the OP_ is simply calling it a matrix (as perhaps they're unfamiliar with the term data.frame.)

Answer (score 0):

You get the NA's when `R` doesn't know how to convert something to a number.

Specifically, the quotation mark in your output tells me that you have one (several) LNG string of numbers.  To see why this is bad, try:  `as.nmeric("-0.00285  -0.0028274")`

I don't know what your raw data is like, but as @alexwhan mentioned, the culprit is probably in your call to `read.table`

To fix it, try explicitly setting the sep argument (ie, next to where you have header)

I would suggest opening up the raw file in a simple text editor (TextEdit.app or notepad, not Word) and seeing how they are separated.  M guess is

```
   ..., sep="\t"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: read.table is not the problem. If you download and examine the file, the columns are mostly space-delimited with the exception of columns 1 and 2, which are separated by tab. The OP read.table() call reads the file correctly.

Comment: I don't have access to the file at the moment, but if the file has different delimiters, then that is exactly the problem.  Are you sure they are not all tab delimd?   Either way, the quote marks in the OP's post indicate that the data is not getting read in as expected, hence the NA's. I would venture to say that if they counted the number of NAs it would be closer to the Nebraska of rows than to the number of expected elements.

Comment: I do have access to the file. The delimiters are as I described (examined using hexdump). And this is not a problem. From ?read.table(): "If ‘sep = ""’ (the default for ‘read.table’) the separator is ‘white space’, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns." In other words, sep = "\t" is only required if all delimiters are tabs.

Comment: Good point on the white space.  The OP is clearly getting a single string per row.  What would you guess is causing that?

Comment: I have no idea how they achieved that. If I run as.matrix(expData) I get the expected result: a 7502 x 1901 matrix where the elements are quoted characters.