# Why does as.numeric convert a matrix to a vector, and how do I keep the result as a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, coercion

The following code converts a 3x3 logical matrix into a vector with 9 elements:

```
as.numeric(matrix(rep(FALSE, 9), nrow = 3))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why is this happening and how do I avoid this? Apologies if this has been asked before, the only reference I could find was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15490316/

Comment: Well, a `matrix` *is* a vector. It just has the `dim` attribute. Investigating `?is.matrix` yields "*is.matrix returns TRUE if x is a vector and has a "dim" attribute of length*". `as.numeric` strips this attribute so it become just a vector. If you'll see `as.numeric` source code you will see it calls `as.double`. If you''ll investigate `?as.double` docs, you will find that: "*as.double attempts to coerce its argument to be of double type: like as.vector it strips attributes including names.*". So this whole thing sums up into just reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the other half of the question.

Comment: Btw, you can store your attributes (such as `dim` or `dimnames` and then reassign them back). for instance `a <- attributes(m) ; m <- as.numeric(m) ; attributes(m) <- a`. Though `m[] <- as.numeric(m)` is probably the easiset approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create an object earlier and then assign the output back to it

```
m1 <- matrix(rep(FALSE, 9), nrow = 3)
m1[] <- as.numeric(m1)
```

or a hacky option is

```
+(matrix(rep(FALSE, 9), nrow = 3))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
```

Or assign with the `dim`

```
`dim<-`(as.numeric(matrix(rep(FALSE, 9), nrow = 3)), c(3, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, does the `+`, or I guess `1 * ` option work even if the matrix has characters or factors in it? Also, do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Alex It is for converting the logical, but if you have `character`s etc, the first or third option should work

Comment: You can do `apply(matrix(rep(FALSE, 9), nrow = 3), c(1, 2), as.numeric)` to retain the matrix structure

Comment: it's crazy that you have to go to so much effort to retain the matrix structure.

Comment: @Alex A matrix is basically a vector with dimensions.  So, if the dimension structure is distorted by as.numeric, then it can be set with `dim<-`